# Can developers access user identifiable information from their iPhone app downloads? How about Android phones?

Tags: iphone, android, ios4, mobile, itunes

When users download iPhone apps, can developers gain access to user identifiable information (e.g., full name, email address, iTunes account)?

How about Android app downloads?

We believe the answer is no, but just wanted to verify the privacy policies on the respective platforms.

So developers just see random IDs representing unique users?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is **no**. This is not possible. For good reason.

Answer (score 1):

With purchased apps from the Android Market, you have access to the name and shipping address, along with a @checkout.google.com email address to contact the purchased.